Nav2 MPPI Controller how to control the speed
I'm currently working on a project involving a four-wheeled, car-like robot with Ackermann configuration. To control its movement, I've opted for the MPPI Controller, known for its compatibility with Ackermann cars in Nav2.
In this project, I aim for the robot to maintain a fixed distance of 4 meters from a person who is following it. The plan is for the robot to generate a path using the global planner and only move forward when the person (represented as a differential drive robot in Gazebo) is within this 4-meter range.
To achieve this, I plan to utilize the person's odometry data, controlled manually using teleop_keyboard.
My question is: How can I implement speed control with the MPPI Controller? Are there any alternative approaches that might be more effective?
Any help or suggest is welcome.
Thank you very much!
